# Realizar consulta de totales entre dos tablas sin duplicar los valores

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito combinar 2 tablas, hacer un resumen y obtener sus diferencias. En la tabla servicios tengo el costo del servicio, en la tabla pagos tengo los montos y medios de pagos asociados, como puedo hacer un resumen de tal manera que independiente de la cantidad de medios de pago no se duplique el valor del servicio.

Estoy en etapa de diseño, por lo que también puedo cambiar el diseño de las tablas si la solución lo amerita.

**Tabla1_Servicios**

```
 ID_Serv    Servicio     Monto  
 1          59927840701  118.441,50
```

**Tabla2_Pagos**

```
 ID_Pago    Pago     Monto          ID_Serv
 3          Debito   39.480,50      1
 4          Credito  78.961,00      1
```

**Consulta_Totales**

```
 Total_Servicios    Total_Pagos     Diferencia  
 236.883,00         118.441,50      -118.441,50
```

** Error en **Total_Servicio**, se duplica al tener el mismo indice asociado 2 veces

Answer (score 0):

buen día.
Si no me equivoco, te refieres al uso de group by, revisa este enlace [enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx), de todas formas hice un ejemplo espero haber entendido bien la pregunta, te pediría mas información pero no puedo hacer comentarios en tu pregunta por no contar con la reputación necesaria aún.

```
declare @servicios as table(
    id_serv  int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    servicio bigint not null,
    monto decimal(16,4) 
);

declare @pagos as table(
    id_pago int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    pago varchar(100),
    monto decimal(16, 4),
    id_serv int 
);

insert into @servicios(servicio, monto) values(59927840701, 118441.50 ),  
    (59927840702, 118441.50),(59927840703, 543  )
insert into @pagos(pago, monto, id_serv) values('Debito', 39480.50, 1), 
    ('Credito', 78961.00, 1),('Debito', 0, 2), ('Credito',59220.7500 , 2)


select 
    sum(pag.monto) as total_pagos,
    max(ser.monto) as total_servicios,
    max(ser.monto) - sum(pag.monto) as diferencia,
    max(ser.servicio) as servicio
from @pagos  pag 
inner join @servicios as ser  on ser.id_serv = pag.id_serv
group by ser.id_serv
```